# Are there mechanics to make your own deities?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I noticed in *The Inner Sea World Guide* that most core deities seem to have 5 domains associated with them, and every other deity has 4.

I'm trying to make a few additions to the list for my campaign but didn't want to disrupt the balance too much.  My guess would be that I can just make one and give it the appropriate number of domains?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your goal is to make your created deities fit in with the existing deity mechanics and/or the existing Pathfinder deity style as much as possible, then I would highly recommend getting the [*Gods and Magic* book by Sean Reynolds](http://paizo.com/products/btpy85eh?Pathfinder-Chronicles-Gods-Magic). This is a Paizo campaign setting guide for the official Pathfinder setting, but the PDF is only $13 USD and contains a ton of detail on the existing deities in Pathfinder:

> Creators of life, forgers of worlds, and rulers of reality—these are the gods and goddesses of the world. They have existed for eons. The countless worlds of the Great Beyond are their playgrounds and battlefields. Yet for all their vast power, it is not the gods of Golarion who shape nations and write history—this task falls instead to their greatest creations: the mortal races of the world. It is through their priests and paladins, their clerics and cultists that the gods make their will known in this world, be it for good or ill.
>
> In Gods and Magic, you will learn not only of the core twenty deities of the Pathfinder Chronicles campaign setting, but of a multitude of other deities whose flocks, while smaller and more isolated, have just as much potential for greatness. Yet this book isn’t just for clerics—religion and faith are important factors in the lives of many, be they stalwart paladins, brave rangers, mysterious druids, or dedicated monks. Even those whose talents lie beyond the divine, such as the scholarly wizard or the god-fearing barbarian, find that faith has its advantages.
>
> Within this 64-page book you will find:
>
> - Detailed descriptions of the core twenty deities of the Pathfinder Chronicles campaign setting, complete with symbols and full illustrations
> - Details on over 40 additional deities, including the gods of dwarves and elves, gnomes and halflings, giants and dragons, and more
> - Over 20 new spells associated with the most powerful religions, yet usable by both arcane and divine spellcasters
> - Dozens of new magic items keyed to the world’s religions, ranging from minor trinkets to powerful artifacts

By comparison you should be able to construct your own with as much or as little detail necessary for your campaign.

Answer (score 4):

There are no core rules that I know of for creating your own deities. Of course there may be unforeseen consequences associated with combining any four or five domains, but there are so many such combinations that evaluating them all is a wasted effort.

I wouldn't worry about it. Pathfinder's existing balance issues will far outweigh any you might introduce by creating a few custom deities.

As a side note, don't forget to pick your new deities' alignments and favored weapons.

Comment: And iconography including holy symbol, time of prayer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be [The Primal Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Primal_Order).  It's an old book (the first published by WotC), but available on [Drive Thru RPG](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/118293/The-Primal-Order?term=Primal%20Order).

> The Primal OrderTM reigns supreme. Also known as TPO, The Primal Order
>   is the premiere resource for using religions and deities effectively
>   and creatively in roleplaying games. Explore how deities gain power,
>   learn why they need worshippers and temples, discover why they provide
>   their priests with spells, and much more. TPO also offers detailed
>   guidelines for the creation of artifacts, suggesting strategies for
>   their design and use.
>
> Heralded since its initial release as one of the most innovative and
>   useful roleplaying supplements ever published, TPO is an invaluable
>   tool for campaign development. Get ready—your roleplaying experience
>   is about to be transformed!

I used it with great effect in more than one game to

- allow characters to cross that threshold from mortality to godhood
- play a campaign that the characters started as gods
- create religions and such for campaigns
- stat up gods based not on the rules of the game, but rules that made them seem like gods

I highly recommend it, and am glad that it's available again.  There were three other books also- Pawns, The Opening Move, Chessboards, The Planes of Possibility, and Knights, Strategies in Motion.  I recommend the latter two more than the first.